Wordpress config, custom post types, advice/guidance needed
Looking for a bit of advice/guidance.
I have a client who has a complicated setup (also made complicated by way of mess in the cms loads of copies and nonsensical approach to naming of templates/content), they use a white labelled version of beaver builder (BB). They have multiple custom post types fields (for events, press, blogs, videos etc there are about 8 in total). Some of these custom post type fields have content on the pages that is gated (like a white paper or infographic). Each time you create a new gated (and sometimes non-gated) content on one of those custom post types you need to create a separate template in BB and then link that template to the content (for each one its crazy). Rest of the site is pretty standard, usual business copy, business pages etc (not an ecommerce site just a b2b).
My question is 2 fold. 1, Does it need to be that complicated (given the multiple post types) and 2 how would you approach this as a new build? (Same approach with custom post types etc?). I should also add in this client uses iframed Salesforce forms, each form is unique to the page/content, ie the redirect after form fill is handled by Salesforce not redirected to WP.
Thank you in advance.

when you create a new template in BB, is that manually ? you can certainly automate this step and then if everything is automated, you leave the client in his mess ;-) but this would be then complicated to make evolve.

No everything is manual. You have to create a new template and then assign it to the post item EVERY time. @mmm
